# iOS AppUITests - Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, provisioning-profile, xcode-ui-testing

I am developing an iOS app. When i am running Tests/UITests with `Command + U` from Xcode, Build is failed with the below error. All of my targets provisioning profiles and certificates are okey, except i put Don't Code Sign for AppUITests target. Is there any way to run full unit & ui tests without profiles, for example on simulator?

Error:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run uitest on real device, different profile is required to configure as uitest target runs on different process as different app.

For simulator, developer provisioning profile is ok. But if you want to run ui tests on real devices, you need separate developer provisioning profile.

Comment: Could you, please, expand your answer? I am facing the same issue. Do I need to create an additional provisioning profile on Developer Portal?

Comment: @kerd yes you have to create new profiles in dev portal. Just like main target UI test target also need different profiles.

Comment: should it be a Development or Ad Hoc provisioning profile?

Comment: @kerd if you want to run UITests while running using Xcode you need development.